# How do I add buttons to Aero Peek in VB6?

Tags: api, windows-7, vb6, aero

I'm working on a program that can play songs off an iPod. I want to be able to put functional Back, Play/Pause and Next buttons on its Aero Peek thumbnail like this:
[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/1yua0m.png]

For those who can't see it: http://i45.tinypic.com/1yua0m.png

How would I do this in VB6?

**EDIT:** Can I also create a jump list for my app? For this app, I only need taskbar jump lists. For others, I'll need taskbar and start menu jump lists so posting code to achieve both would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2:** I have uploaded a sample of how to use the ITaskBarList3 interface to add buttons to the window preview (and handle their click events), add an icon overlay, clip the window preview and add a progress bar to the program's taskbutton. Download it [here](http://www.winntsoft.host22.com/Downloads/InternalApps/ITaskBarList3.zip).

Comment: Can you check the image URL - I can't see it.

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/1yua0m.png

Comment: That's also a window thumbnail, not [Aero Peek](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/peek)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Taskbar Thumbnail Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thumbbars) feature of Windows Explorer. This does use a COM interface so I don't know how practical it is to use for VB but I beliver the IDLs are available if you look.

You can also find a [C# example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [UI guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511446.aspx#thumbnail) on MSDN.

The Jumplist information is also covered on the same pages.

Comment: OK, I'll upload a sample later.

Comment: The only problem is that it likes to crash both the program and IDE alot. It resides with a BASS module, and I don't know if BASS is interfering with it or what. It seems much more stable when used in an entirely new project without BASS. Im going to need to find out why it makes VB6 so unstable (compiled EXE is also unstable with the thumbnail toolbar code added).